# One interview question. about debugging

Tags: debugging

I have been asked this question today.

When debugging, there is an error. But after you add one printf() line. No error.
What are errors can cause this.

This is an open question. So just let me say what I thought.

My answer was not logical at that time. (such as, maybe some memory error? maybe have concurrency issue?)
So what to hear sth you may have.

Some people may say this is not a good or not a reasonable question. But when we dealing with interview, we have no choice. We need to say what ever logical and make it make sende. :)

Comment: what is the error that you are assuming/talking about?

Comment: no context. He just let me answer it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concurrency issue is pretty valid. An I/O operation such as `printf` takes **really long** compared to other operations, and this sometimes hides a race condition (the problem doesn't go away, it just manifests less often - harder to debug).

Imagine somebody comes up with this flawed idea:

- Start a thread
- Initialize some memory location that will be read by that thread

At this point there's no telling what will happen. If the thread starts really quick, it will read the memory location before the starting thread has a chance to write it. If however the new thread simply prints "Oh hay, I'm a new thread" before reading the variable, it has a pretty good chance to read valid results. Of course, in 1/10 cases it *will* fail and it will be a pain to debug.

Comment: Also, on most platforms, 'printf' acts as a memory barrier, since the compiler has no idea what variables it might access.

Answer (score 3):

The trigger-word he was looking for was "[heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug)" - a bug that disappears when trying to study it.

I would list three common errors that may cause this in order of likeliness:

1. The `printf-statements` has *sideeffects*. In the simplest case something like `printf("%d", i++);`. In this case the code *always* works wihtout the statement and *never* when its there.
2. As already mentioned - Race conditions between threads where the `printf` introduces a slight delay reducing the likelihood that the bug will appear. The bug may however still appear even without the statement.
3. Memory corruption - The stack or heap was corrupted by bad pointer code at a previous point. The call to `printf` reveals this and crashes. Also in this case the program will likely crash later even without the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my guesses:

The `printf()` was modifying some variable; say an argument was `++i`

`printf()` is an i/o operation, which takes a considerable time WRT the other non-i/o operations. Maybe it prevented some race condition.

`printf()` returns some value. Maybe the function had an `int` return type but no `return` statement, so in the assembly (at least this happens in gcc, x86-64) the last returned value is returned.